# How to take average of times with negative values PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, math

I have an array say:

```
array("10:10:20", "-20:00:10", "14:15:00", "08:10:00");
```

I tried using strtime but it is giving me error as it cant convert negative values to timestamp. Is there any another way?

Comment: Show your attempts in your question

Comment: what does mean -20 hours. is it 20 hours before now? and what about positive value in this case?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/vascowhite/Time for averaging time.

Answer (score 2):

After rereading the question I made a little snippet, the average is a sum of numbers. So i'm guessing this should be correct. To bypass the negative timestamps, you just need to calculate the absolute one, make it negative and add it to the sum.

```
<?php

    $timings = array("10:10:20", "-20:00:10", "14:15:00", "08:10:00");
    //$timings = array("-10:10:20", "-10:10:20", "-10:10:20", "-10:10:20");

    $totalTime = 0;
    foreach($timings as $timing) {
        $isNegativeTime = strpos($timing, '-') !== false;
        $time = strtotime(str_replace('-', '', $timing));
        if ($isNegativeTime) $time *= -1;
        $totalTime += $time;
    }

    $avgTiming = $totalTime / count($timings);
    $isNegativeAvgTime = $avgTiming < 0;
    $avgTiming = date('h:i:s', abs($avgTiming));
    echo ($isNegativeAvgTime ? '-':'').$avgTiming;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 
$moredownvotes = array("10:10:20", "-20:00:10", "14:15:00", "08:10:00");

$nb_lol = count($moredownvotes);

for ($i = 0; $i < ($nb_lol - 1); ++$i)
{
    $pattern = '/^-(.*)/';
    $replacement = '${1}';
    $moredownvotes[$i] = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $moredownvotes[$i]);
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($moredownvotes);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

**Result :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10:10:20
    [1] => 20:00:10
    [2] => 14:15:00
    [3] => 08:10:00
)
```

**NOW u can use DateTime functions or w/e u want**

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $moredownvotes[$i]);
echo date_format($date, 'H:i:s');
```

**RESULT ** : `10:10:20`

[PHP.net createFromFormat function](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: It's still a array of strings - He wants to made the strings to become timestamp. See...